# how to remove css property "element{}"

Tags: javascript, css, properties, background-image, element

Click this link:
[The first prt scr you can see play and mute buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1cQW.jpg)

Click this link:
[The second prt scr I can't see background image, but still javascript working!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsyD9.jpg)

Where is it gone my background image? How can I remove "element" property?

```
element {
    background: transparent url("../images/unmute.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

button#mutebtn {
    background: transparent url("../images/unmute.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can remove an attribute by JQuery:

```
 element.removeAttribute(attributename)
```

check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Make use of the !important in you css file:

   `button#mutebtn {
       background: transparent url("../images/unmute.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;
   }`

(It's considered best practice to avoid !important as much as possible.)

2. Or go to your html page, find the correct line and remove the css background there.

Note: you can't reach `element` in your stylesheet. This is css that is direct/inline implemented in your html file.

I made a example for you, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7usr0cs4/1) fiddle!

Comment: I can't use !important or inline implement style in html, because there are 2 background pictures...?

Comment: Go to the line where you have the right background and at the end of that line you type !important. This makes css to give priority to this background.

Comment: I don't want give it priority on this picture....! Ive got by default unmute.png but I want after click to swap with mute.png?!

Answer (score 0):

If you add inline style to `#mutebtn` in the HTML, it will appear as `element{}` in the inspector.

Check your HTML, and if you need to use the inline style like this:

```
<button id="mutebtn" style="background...."></button>
```

Be careful with the URL of the background attribute, which appears to be fine from the CSS file, but from the HTML file I suppose it should be a different path, usually without the initial `"../"`.

In other words, remove the inline style in your HTML, or change the path there to: `"images/unmute.png"`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var vid, playbtn, seekslider, curtimetext, durtimetext, mutebtn, volumeslider, fullscreenbtn;
function intializePlayer(){
 // Set object references
 vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
 playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
 seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
 curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext");
 durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext");
 mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
 volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
 fullscreenbtn = document.getElementById("fullscreenbtn");
 // Add event listeners
 vid.addEventListener("timeupdate",seektimeupdate,false);
 playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause,false);
 mutebtn.addEventListener("click",vidmute,false);
 fullscreenbtn.addEventListener("click",toggleFullScreen,false);
 seekslider.addEventListener("change",vidSeek,false);
 vid.addEventListener("timeupdate",seektimeupdate,false);
 volumeslider.addEventListener("change",setvolume,false);
 
}
window.onload = intializePlayer;
function playPause(){
 if(vid.paused){
  vid.play();
  playbtn.style.background = "url(../images/pause.png)";
 } else {
  vid.pause();
  playbtn.style.background = "url(../images/play.png)";
 }
}
function vidmute(){
 if(vid.muted){
  vid.muted = false;
  mutebtn.style.background = "url(../images/mute.png)";
 } else {
  vid.muted = true;
  mutebtn.style.background = "url(../images/unmute.png)";
 }
}
function vidSeek(){
 var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
 vid.currentTime = seekto;
}
function seektimeupdate(){
 var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration);
 seekslider.value = nt;
 var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60);
 var cursecs = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60);
 var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
 var dursecs = Math.floor(vid.duration - durmins * 60);
 if(cursecs < 10){ cursecs = "0"+cursecs; }
 if(dursecs < 10){ dursecs = "0"+dursecs; }
 if(curmins < 10){ curmins = "0"+curmins; }
 if(durmins < 10){ durmins = "0"+durmins; }
 curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins+":"+cursecs;
 durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins+":"+dursecs;
}
function setvolume(){
 vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
}
function toggleFullScreen(){
 if(vid.requestFullScreen){
  vid.requestFullScreen();
 } else if(vid.webkitRequestFullScreen){
  vid.webkitRequestFullScreen();
 } else if(vid.mozRequestFullScreen){
  vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
 }
}

  playbtn.style.background = "url(../images/pause.png)";

  playbtn.style.background = "url(../images/play.png)";
```

```css
div#video_player_box {
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
}
div#video_controls_bar {
 padding: 10px;
 color: #CCC;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 width: 100%;
}
button#playpausebtn {
 background: url(../images/pause.png);
 
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 0px none;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.5;
 
}
button#playpausebtn:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
input#seekslider {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 2px;
 
}
input#volumeslider {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 80px;
 padding: 2px;
 
}
button#mutebtn {
 background:url(../images/unmute.png);
 
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 0px none;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.5;
 
 /*--style text button
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0.5em;
 border-radius: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
 background-color: #068EA2;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #BABABA 1%, #FFF 20%);--*/
}
button#mutebtn:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
button#fullscreenbtn {
 background: url(../images/fullscreen.png);
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 0px none;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.5;
 float:right;
 
 /*--style text button
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0.5em;
 border-radius: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
 background-color: #068EA2;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #BABABA 1%, #FFF 20%);--*/
}
button#fullscreenbtn {
 opacity: 1;
}
input[type='range'] {
 -webkit-appearance: none !important;
 background: #000;
 border: #666 1px solid;
 height: 2px;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance: none !important;
 background: #FFF;
 height:10px;
 width:10px;
 border-radius:100%;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="video_player_box">
        <video id="my_video" autoplay>
          <source src="media/echo-hereweare.mp4">
        </video>
        <div id="video_controls_bar">
        <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
        <button id="playpausebtn"></button>
        <button id="mutebtn"></button>
        <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1">
<span id="curtimetext"></span> / <span id="durtimetext">
</span><button id="fullscreenbtn">[&nbsp;]</button>   
        </div>
        <!--end video_controls_bar -->
        </div>
        <!--end video_player_box -->
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7usr0cs4/1/ Here you go. I added a playbutton as example now you can do the rest. If my answer helped you please check it as answered!

Comment: Btw next time add your code as a JS fiddle!

Comment: Did you get it to work?